# Difference of two sets of tuples in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two sets of tuples `a` and `b`.

```
a = set([(1,'a'),(34,'b'), (82,'c')])
b = set([(8,'a'),(98,'c')])
```

I want a set `c` such that

```
c = set([(34,'b')])
```

What is the most efficient way of doing this operation in python ?

Comment: you probably want to start by transforming your set of tuples in a dict: `{k: v for (v, k) in a}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess O(n) is the most efficient:

```
>>> b2 = {x for n,x in b}
>>> c = {(n,x) for (n,x) in a if x not in b2}
>>> c
{(34, 'b')}
```

Comment: This is indeed the most efficient one, after benchmarking of all the answers I found. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would start by using dicts instead of sets for a and b:

```
a = {k: v for (v, k) in a}
b = {k: v for (v, k) in b}
```

Then, it is just a matter of taking the content of `a` that is not in `b`

```
print [(k, a[k]) for k in set(a.keys()) - set(b.keys())]
```

or

```
b_keys = set(b.keys())
print [(k,v) for (k,v) in a.items() if k not in b_keys}
```

Comment: Watch out - that last snippet is recomputing `set(b.keys())` on every iteration.