# Python create diff of two file

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
data1= [open("lis1.json", 'r')]
data2= [open('list2.json', 'r')]


first_set = set(map(tuple, data1))
second_set = set(map(tuple, data2))


x= (first_set-second_set)

print(x)
```

I am attempting to view two list and get the data in list 1 that are not in list two. the issue is list one format for both set of data is as below :

```
data1= ["Jane Doe", 98132]["John Doe", 12345]
```

or

```
data1=
[
    "jane doe",
    98132
][
    "john doe",
    12345
]
   data2=["Jane Doe", 98132]["John drew", 8989]["John drew", 8989]["John drew", 8989]
data2= 
[
    "jane doe",
    98132
][
    "john drew",
    8989
]
```

I was expecting

```
x = [["John Doe", 12345]
```

I am comparing a list of users vs call logs so it might have duplicate.

---

in the file I am seeing this in the errors :"Json standard allows only one top-level value"

---

if I use `json(load)`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/diff.py", line 4, in <module>
    data1 = json.load(open("list1.json"))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/json/__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py", line 340, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 19 (char 18)
```

Comment: You need to use `json.load()` to parse the JSON in the files. You're comparing them as strings, not lists.

Comment: And what DID you get?  That particular example isn't going to work because `data1` is a list that contains a file handle.  It's not a list of strings.

Comment: @TimRoberts `tuple(file_object)` will read the file and make a tuple of all the lines.

Comment: This should work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37422290/difference-of-two-sets-of-tuples-in-python

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32815640/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-dictionaries-in-python

Comment: If your file contains `data1= ["Jane Doe", 98132]["John Doe", 12345]`, that's not a JSON. You would need to write a parser for such format yourself. Just for completeness: it's not valid Python code either.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `json.load()` to parse the JSON.

```
data1 = json.load(open("list1.json"))
data2 = json.load(open("list2.json"))
```

Comment: I am getting a parsing error due to the fact that the data has [] brackets as oppose to {} anything I can do either change the data or properly convert it

Comment: That shouldn't cause a parsing error. `[]` is used for creating lists, `{}` is for dictionaries. Can you update the question and add a sample of the JSON file?

Comment: Hello Barmar, thanks for your help and I have added more information

Comment: Your files are not proper JSON. I think you've written multiple JSONs to the same file, instead of combing everything into an array and then writing it as a single JSON.

Comment: The JSON should look like `[["Jane Doe", 98132],["John Doe", 12345]]`